# TeamCity selects only 1 version of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tfs, msbuild, teamcity

**In short:**

How can I build and deploy using TeamCity multiple versions of jQuery?

**Long way:**

existing info:

1. Two files from jQuery (jquery-2.1.1.js and jquery-2.1.3.js)  are checked into the source control (TFS) in absolutely same 100% way (Build Action -> "Context"). In parallel, in the same directory, all identical.
2. Local Build and deploy using MSStudio 12 works without any issues copying at the end of the build both files into Scripts directory
3. when it runs from TeamCity, it fails to find the relevant "meant to be copied" files and comes back with the following error:

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets(608,
>   5): Copying file Scripts\jquery-2.1.3.js to
>   obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Scripts\jquery-2.1.3.js failed.
>   Could not find file 'Scripts\jquery-2.1.3.js'"

Would someone help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: I apologise if this is a stupid question, but are you 100% sure 2.1.3 is checked into TFS? Can you see this file in the working directory on the server running the TeamCity Agent, where it has checked out all of the code from TFS?

Comment: Question is perfect! In fact, it sort of gives more hints that i have not managed to read as yet:
1.   2.1.3 is definitely in TFS  
2. TeamCity gets both of them out,
3. BUT because I also have NuGet installed, it gets into the download from TFS directory 2.1.4 version as well!!!!
4. though out of three different scripts only the first one getting copied into deployment output directory

Comment: Thank you to "FormigaNinja " for getting my formatting right.!